# What can qemu's virtio-blk's drive parameter be set to

Tags: qemu, pci

I'm trying to start qemu with a virtio disk controller and it says:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -S -gdb tcp::9000 --nographic --enable-kvm -cpu host -m 8192 -device virtio-blk-pci,drive=c,scsi=off -drive file=hard.disk,if=virtio,format=raw -fda floppy.img                                                           
qemu-system-x86_64: -device virtio-blk-pci,drive=c,scsi=off: Property 'virtio-blk-device.drive' can't find value 'c'
```

The reason I'm using the -device parameter is that I already tried just if=virtio on -drive but when I scanned the PCI devices no virtio block device showed up.

I'm writing my own OS from scratch.

How do I get this virtio PCI device to appear?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The drive option of -device should be set to the ID of a drive you created with -drive:

-drive id=mydrive,file=foo.img,...  -device virtio-blk-pci,drive=mydrive,...

This is a common pattern with QEMU options.

PS: if you're connecting the drive created with -drive to a device via the "give it an ID name and the specify it in a -device option" then you don't want to pass if=virtio. ("if=virtio" means "try to automatically connect this drive to a virtio interface", and QEMU will complain that you've asked it to connect the drive twice, once automatically and once explicitly.)

Comment: I also needed to pass if=none to -drive and then it accepted it, but the results are the same as if I just use -drive with if=virtio: When I hunt through the PCI devices for those with vendor id 1AF4, all I get is one network device. Is it true that the virtio mass storage device should have that vendor id?

Comment: I figured it out. Osdev had misled me into thinking the "Subsystem ID field in the PCI Configuration Space" had to be 2. This is not so for the 1AF4 device I find, but it does have a PCI Device ID of 0x1001 which makes it a block device.